# Find Out my Graphics Memory Two Cards Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: graphics, playonlinux

I am trying to install Age of Empires III on my PC under Playonlinux, but I am having some problems with graphics memory.  It asks for the graphics memory on the installer.

I tried what some tutorials suggested, but they are designed for one card.  I have two (both ATI) to support my two VGA monitors.  Can someone please say how I could find the memory?

Comment: `lspci -v | grep -iA2 memory` will show you enough info, if that what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The command `dmesg` shows lots of information about system hardware. To see all of that you should edit Terminal preferences to check **unlimited** scrollback.

However it seems you can find out graphics memory by:

`dmesg | grep -i graphics`

I tried it on two systems and get outputs including a same line like:

```
[drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
```

You can also find AGP and GTT units using `dmesg | grep -i agp` and `dmesg | grep -i gtt`. (The `-i` option makes it ignore case distinctions.)

I hope this will help.